# Make visual studio check for coding convetions and automatically report/correct them

Tags: visual-studio

There are c# codding conventions listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions
Is there some way to set Visual studio(2019) to automatically check if my code respects them and if not show some warning in the error list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New versions of the C# compiler perform some style enforcement according to rules specified in a `.editorconfig` file.

For even greater control, I would suggest you look at StyleCop.Analyzers. It is a Roslyn Analyzer that ships as a NuGet package you can add to your projects.

You can configure it to provide warnings or errors when code does not match the style rules you specify.

It is very flexible, and has the added benefit that the rules apply to all developers of the project, which forces everyone to adhere to the code style rules in order to have the build pass cleanly.

https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers

https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio comes with code style checks and options to enforce them when building.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019

Comment: do you know if default config is the same as one mentioned on coding conventions webpage?